# SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers during foreachpartition

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use `foreachPartition` to run some code on each executor, essentially calling an API for data in each partition.

For the function being called by `foreachPartition`, is it possible to pass it arguments, besides the Iterator[rows]? I need to pass an object instance to the function to make some API calls, but it seems Spark is pickling the outer class `SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers`.

```
    def process_event(api: APIClass, rows):
        for row in rows:
            print(row.name)
            self.api.do_call(row.name)
```